# What does 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable mean

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am trying to change the background colour of the app when the user changes the theme style. Everything works fine until I add an if statement  to change the background colour to a certain when the theme is changed in the kv file. I found out that `'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` has to do with trying to call a variable as an integer when it is an array. But I have no arrays anywhere in my code.

Main.py

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivymd.uix.tab import MDTabsBase
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

class MainScreen(Screen):
    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        pass
class MainApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls = ThemeManager()
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Gray"
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = "300"

        return Builder.load_file(GUI)

    def change_screen(self, screen_name, screen_direction):
        screen_manager = self.root.ids["screen_manager"]
        screen_manager.current = screen_name
        screen_manager.transition.direction = screen_direction
        # print(screen_name)

    def return_empty(self):
        print(self.theme_cls.primary_color)

    def on_tab_switch(self):
        pass

    def dark_theme(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"

    def light_theme(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

kv file

```
<MainScreen>:
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_light\
            if app.theme_cls.theme_style == 'Light'\
                else app.theme_cls.primary_dark

        MDToolbar:
            md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_dark
                if app.theme_cls.theme_style == "Light"\
                    else app.theme_cls.primary_dark
            title: "MyDhikr"
            right_action_items: [["account-child-circle", lambda x: app.return_empty()]]

        MDBottomNavigation:
            #panel_color: .2, .2, .2, 1
            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name: "screen_1"
                icon: "home"

                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: "vertical"

                    MDTabs:
                        id: tabs
                        on_tab_switch: app.on_tab_switch()
                        lock_swiping: False
                        Tab:
                            text: "Flow"
                            ScrollView:
                                MDList:
                                    spacing: dp(10)
                                    padding: dp(20)
                                    MDLabel:
                                        id: streak
                                        text: "STREAK"
                                        halign: "center"
                                        font_style: "H4"
                                        theme_text_color: "Custom"
                                    TwoLineAvatarIconListItem:
                                        text: "SubhanAllah"
                                        secondary_text: "Number = 33"
                                    TwoLineAvatarIconListItem:
                                        text: "SubhanAllah"
                                        secondary_text: "Number = 33"
                                    TwoLineAvatarIconListItem:
                                        text: "SubhanAllah"
                                        secondary_text: "Number = 33"


                        Tab: #slide Screen
                            text: "Quick"
                            BoxLayout:
                                orientation: "vertical"
                                MDIconButton:
                                    icon: "magnify"
                                   # halign: "center"
                                MDLabel:
                                    text: "SubhanAllah"
                                    halign: "center"
                                    valign: "center"

            MDBottomNavigationItem: # settings screen
                name: "screen_2"
                icon: "menu"

                ScrollView:
                    #orientation: "vertical"
                    MDList:
                        OneLineAvatarIconListItem:
                            text: "Language"
                            on_release:
                                print(app.change_screen("language_screen", "left"))
                            IconRightWidget:
                                icon: "chevron-right"

                        OneLineAvatarIconListItem:
                            text: "Notification"
                            on_release:
                                print(app.change_screen("notification_screen", "left"))
                            IconRightWidget:
                                icon: "chevron-right"

                        OneLineAvatarIconListItem:
                            text: "Theme"
                            on_release:
                                print(app.change_screen("theme_screen", "left"))
                            IconRightWidget:
                                icon: "chevron-right"

<Tab>:
    MDLabel:
        id: label
```

the full traceback

```
   File "C:/Users/Dell/PycharmProjects/MyDhikr_2.0/main.py", line 65, in <module>
     MainApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\untitled2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 828, in run
     self.load_kv(filename=self.kv_file)
   File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\untitled2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 599, in load_kv
     root = Builder.load_file(rfilename)
   File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\untitled2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 301, in load_file
     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\untitled2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 368, in load_string
     parser = Parser(content=string, filename=fn)
   File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\untitled2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 401, in __init__
     self.parse(content)
   File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\untitled2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 507, in parse
     self.execute_directives()
   File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\untitled2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 461, in execute_directives
     kivy.lang.builder.Builder.load_file(ref)
   File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\untitled2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 301, in load_file
     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\untitled2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 368, in load_string
     parser = Parser(content=string, filename=fn)
   File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\untitled2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 401, in __init__
     self.parse(content)
   File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\untitled2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 510, in parse
     objects, remaining_lines = self.parse_level(0, lines)
   File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\untitled2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 614, in parse_level
     level + 1, lines[i:], spaces)
   File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\untitled2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 673, in parse_level
     if current_property[:3] == 'on_':
 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: "trying to call a variable as an integer when it is an array". No, it's trying to use it as a list when it's `None`.

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: It means you're using the subscript operator `x[y]` when the `x` is `None`.

Comment: I only see this operator used in `change_screen()`, but the traceback should point you to it.

Comment: @gilch what do you mean by subscript operator.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `kv` file. The section:

```
    MDToolbar:
        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_dark
            if app.theme_cls.theme_style == "Light"\
                else app.theme_cls.primary_dark
```

is missing a '\'. It should be:

```
    MDToolbar:
        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_dark\
            if app.theme_cls.theme_style == "Light"\
                else app.theme_cls.primary_dark
```

Comment: I'm still receiving the same error with that correction.

Comment: Make sure that you do not have any characters after the '\', it is intended to escape the newline that follows it.

Comment: There are no new characters after it

Comment: Are there ANY characters after any of the '\' characters?

Comment: No there isn't any character after the '\'

Comment: If the error message is showing the same traceback, then you can see that the error is occurring during the parsing of your 'kv' file. If the traceback is different now, then you are seeing a different problem.